# Deleting Files in windows XP network

Tags: windows, windows-xp, sp3

How can I tell if anyone is copying or deleting my files using `\\my computer name\c$` with administrative rights in Windows XP?

The network is a 2003 Advanced server domain.

Comment: Turn on [File Auditing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399).

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you would need to enable File Auditing:

1. Click Start, click Control Panel, click Performance and Maintenance,
   and then click Administrative Tools.
2. Double-click Local Security Policy.
3. In the left pane, double-click Local Policies to expand it.
4. In the left pane, click Audit Policy to display the individual policy    settings in the right pane.
5. Double-click Audit object access.
6. To audit successful access of specified files, folders and printers,    select the Success check box.
7. To audit unsuccessful access to these objects, select the Failure    check box.
8. To enable auditing of both, select both check boxes.
9. Click OK.

Once this is done, you will need to pick which files and folders to audit:

1. In Windows Explorer, locate the file or folder you want to audit. To
   audit a printer, locate it by clicking Start, and then clicking
   Printers and Faxes.
2. Right-click the file, folder, or printer that you want to audit, and
   then click Properties.
3. Click the Security tab, and then click Advanced.
4. Click the Auditing tab, and then click Add.
5. In the Enter the object name to select box, type the name of the user
   or group whose access you want to audit. You can browse the computer
   for names by clicking Advanced, and then clicking Find Now in the
   Select User or Group dialog box.
6. Click OK.
7. Select the Successful or Failed check boxes for the actions you want
   to audit, and then click OK.
8. Click OK, and then click OK.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399